# 7bit patterns for 8bit and unicode engines

Tags: xetex, luatex, hyphenation

Consider the following dummy file

```
\bgroup
\catcode`^^F1=11
\lccode "F1="F1
\patterns{
1b 1c 1d 1f 1g 1h 1j 1k 1l 1m 1n 1^^f1 1p 1q 1r 1s 1t 1v 1w 1x 1y 1z
}
\egroup
\endinput
```

Is it *technically feasible, though probably incorrect*, to use this 7bit representation of hyphenation patterns in LuaTeX or XeTeX, provided that the glyphs do not exceed the 255 index limit of 8bit input/output? Here, adding an hyphenation pattern for basque `ñ` along with the other 7bit consonants.

Comment: what you show are not 8bit patterns really  they are unicode patterns that just happen to not have entries above char255, that is quite common, eg the patterns for English

Comment: lualatex will use the patterns used for pdftex with Babel if you specify 8bit T1 encoding, but it's almost always better to use TU unicode encoded fonts with lualatex

Comment: you don't have to write it as `^^F1` you could simply use `ñ`

Comment: but if I use `ñ` directly, that would save the pattern in utf8, and that would render it useless if I try these patterns on an 8bit engine, correct?

Comment: The encoding you save the file in is (usually) a setting in your editor not a feature of the characters you used.  If you write the file in ascii with `^^F1` you save worrying about the file save but you rely on using an encoding where F1 does indeed refer to `ñ`  which happens to be the case for T1 but not all Unicode in the 0-FF range do have the same nuber in T1 encoding so if you needed other characters that have different numeric values in legacy encodings, using `^^` is more problematic.

Answer (score 1):

What you show are not 8bit patterns really; they are unicode patterns that just happen to not have entries above char255, that is quite common, eg the patterns for English.

lualatex will use the patterns used for pdftex with Babel if you specify 8bit T1 encoding, but it's almost always better to use TU unicode encoded fonts with Unicode TeX engines.

You don't have to write it as `^^F1` you could simply use `ñ`

`ñ` has catcode 11 by default in plain and latex formats with luatex and xetex, so you probably don't need the catcode and lccode settings (depending on where you use the code shown)

Comment: so, perhaps it would be better to say that that is a 7bit representation of patterns within the 255 range, in double caret `^^` notation: they are ready to go for XeTeX or LuaTeX; and the `\lccode` and `\catcode` definitions are harmless on the Unicode engines, but allow them to work on PDFTeX or DEKTeX: correct?

Comment: @jarnosz as noted under the question, for F1 it happens to be the same number used for Unicode and for T1 and LY1 encodings so yes you can share the file, but other letters that is not the case, so in general you can not avoid separate files or conditional code.

Comment: as long as these are supersets of Latin1, it is safe, then...

Comment: but that rules out all the font encodings used by pdflatex. @jarnosz

Comment: @jarnosz you can't have an 8-bit superset of latin1, as that's all 256 characters so 8-bit encodings are latin-1 or not latin-1. Latex supported `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` but never supported `\usepackage[latin1]{fontenc}` and no tex font metrics were produced in that encoing. T1 is "close" and LY1 a bit closer but  neither has all characters in the 0-255 range having the latin1/unicode position.

Comment: for example German `\ss` ß is hex DF (223) in Unicode and Latin 1 but hex FF (255) in T1, so if you want German patterns using `^^` you need `^^DF` or `^^FF` depending on the system.

Comment: I see all your points; that's why the answer to my question is on the affirmative: it is technically possible, but incorrect.